# How to convert a datatype of pandas dataframe from str to float in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, types

```
import pandas as pd
d=[('Shubham',24),
   ('Shrikant',58),
   ('na',34)]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['Name','Age'])
df.dtypes
```

Output:
Name    object

Age      int32

dtype: object

How do I convert the datatype of 'Name' column to float ?

```
df['Name'].astype(float)
```

Getting below error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'na'

Comment: What floating point number do you want the name "Shubham" to become?  14.8?

Comment: What is your expected output and how do you form the logic for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean converting the name into number then no, string can't be turn into number directly using `astype` for what I know. If you meant to encode it then it is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
d=[('Shubham',24),
   ('Shrikant',58),
   ('na',34)]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['Name','Age'])
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype('category').cat.codes
print(df.head())
```